# Can you suggest or specify what exact libraries are required for MS Word and Excel?

Tags: java, file-io, java-io

I am using the `document4j` java library to convert `doc` file to `PDF`. I have installed the Microsoft office on my machine. However, I want to know specific files or libraries which are required install only for MS Word and MS Excel from Microsoft Office.

Comment: Can you explain more what library you want and for what purpose you want? If you want a library that can be used to process the above formats you might use Apache POI.

Comment: You can use the Apache POI library. Please refer https://poi.apache.org/

Comment: I understand that you are using the [`document4j`](https://documents4j.com/) library to convert doc to pdf, but it's still not clear what you're asking. You talk about installing software, but installing Microsoft Office, Microsoft Word or Microsoft Office is not required in order to use `document4j`, so this is confusing. Maybe you can rephrase the question?

Answer (score 0):

Apache POI Lib's would help you.

Below is the link

[Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the apache POI OOXML library for excel.

This is a maven repository link.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/4.1.0

Refer this link for sample 
https://www.java67.com/2014/09/how-to-read-write-xlsx-file-in-java-apache-poi-example.html